# Is it possible to breakdown a c++ statement as shown?

Tags: c++, vector, autosar

The statement is taken from a source file that is developed using vector autosar adaptive davinci APIs/functions etc.

```
adaptive::communication::ServiceHandle find_a_service = services::nameofservice::proxy::serviceproxy::StartSearchService(
    [this](const adaptive::communication::ContainerServiceHandles<services::nameofservice::proxy::serviceproxy::HandleTypes>& handles) 
    { 
        SearchServiceHandler(handles);
    }, adaptive::core::InstanceSpec{ kInstance });
```

I have renamed/obscured names but kept the format intact in the source code. Can anyone help in breaking down this complex statement to several simple ones?

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the really long typenames, what exactly do you consider "complex" about this line?

Comment: This is not possible without knowing the full details of the types involved, but a first approximation could be to extract the arguments to that method call to separate variables. This is mechanically simple: `auto callback = [this](...){...}; auto instanceSpec = adaptive::core::InstanceSpec{kInstance}; ...StartSearchService(callback, instanceSpec);`

Comment: @UnholySheep StartSearchService(abc , xyz); where abc contains [this](const namespaces<morenames> & handles) {other function call}

Feels like a lot of nested things. How did you interpret the whole statement?

Comment: It's a function call with a lambda expression as first argument and an object of type `adaptive::core::InstanceSpec` as second argument

Comment: do you mean "breakdown" as writing in several sort lines or break down as writing down what very part means? Mostly it impossible to do both without knowing details, but you can create aliases and writ lambda in separate line instead of inline use.

Comment: It's a variable `find_a_service` being initialised with the result of a function call `StartSearchService`. The function is passed two arguments, The first is a *lambda* `[this](...) { ... }` and the second is a *temporary* of type `InstanceSpec`.

Comment: To be clear, you already know what a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is, am I right?

Comment: The [tag:davinci] tag is not for DaVinci Developer by Vector. I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While aliasing every name I can, this is rather simple statement, formatted for readability:

```
ServiceHandler find_a_service = 
            StartSearchService ( [this](const HandleContainer<Htypes>& handles ) {
                    SearchServiceHandler(handles);
            }, 
            InstanceSpec{kInstance} );
```

It declares some variable `find_a_service`, intialized by some expression. It's unknown that `StartSearchService` is a type or a function, or a name of callable object.

First argument of  `StartSearchService`  argument is a lambda expression, which captures `this`, takes a const reference to `HandleContainer<Htypes>` as a parameter, and calls some *callable*  with it as argument.

Second argument of  `StartSearchService` is a temporal value, resulting from an expression of type `InstanceSpec`, initialized by list `{kInstance}`, whatever these are.

Now you can *carefully* create aliases for each name. You can create type alisases or you can use using declaration.Carefully because you do not want conflicts.

```
//type alias
using ServiceHandler  = adaptive::communication::ServiceHandle;
using HandleContainer = adaptive::communication::ContainerServiceHandles;

// etc.
```

Using declarion would cut fully qualified name to short one:

```
// in function scope:
using adaptive::communication::ContainerServiceHandles;
// you can write ContainerServiceHandles now, but any samely named entity is ambigous now.
```

Finally, fundamental using-namespace (valid ONLY if communication is a namespace):

```
using namespace adaptive::communication;
// all names in namespace adaptive::communication 
// are now valid in local. Ambiguity is possible.
```

The approach isn't without flaws. It may not be even possible to use in such form in template code or with forward declarations. Koenig's name lookup and necessity of namespace to be declared before arise their ugly heads.

You *may* write lambda separate in most cases, but its ill-advised, because you would create a copy of that and original would live until end of scope, which would a) harm optimization b) can have side-effects, everything about those entities is unknown.

```
auto searchPredicate = 
        [this](const HandleContainer<Htypes>& handles ) {
            SearchServiceHandler(handles);
        };
```